# Can't access rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created my apps and everything is there but when I go to my host address, I cannot see anything, it gives me `404 NOT FOUND` error. I also did `rails server` but it seems to hang. It looks like it just stops at `WEBrick:HTTPSERVER#start: pid=3457 port 3000`. And yes, when I ran `rails server` it was under the app folder.

I also went to port 3000, it says `this page is not available`.

When I add an `index.html` file, I can see that file. But this is obviously not what I want.

What else do I need to check to get to my app?

Comment: `rails server` is waiting for input.  Can you include `routes.rb` in your question?  It sounds like you may need a root route.

Comment: Also worth looking at your development log.

Comment: Did you install therubyracer or any other JS runtime env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the default route for your application, also known as `root`.

Add a line like this to your `routes.rb` file:

```
root to: 'newpage.html'
```

Or, if you want to route to a controller, like the `show` method on the `People` controller:

```
root to: 'people#show'
```

Here is the [Rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks, even though everyone said similar things. I think this was clearest one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the app in the new port as:

```
rails s -p 4000
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `root :to => "static#index"` in your routes file and add an index file in public/.